# How to change the string every 1s using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to display quotes on my webpage and I have 10 quotes in an array `quotes[]` .I want to change them every 1s by picking any 1 quote randomly from the array.I want to do this using only javascript.

I used `setTimeout` but everything messed up. Can anyone help me with a dummy code or function that I can use.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach, using `window.setInterval()`:

```
var q = ['quote 1', 'quote 2', 'quote 3', 'pick your own note'];

function quoteChange (target, quotes) {
    if (!quotes || !target) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length),
            text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText'
        target[text] = quotes[n];
    }
}

var change = window.setInterval(function(){
    quoteChange(document.getElementById('demo'), q);
}, 1000);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rFyjs/1/).

References:

- [`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval).

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeOut`.

Should work like a charm if you follow what's indicated in the link below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setInterval`. `setTimeout` is only for 1 time execution.

```
setInterval(function () {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
    var quote = quotes[index];

    //show it in page

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
setInterval ( ChangeText, 1000 ); //Function Name,Time to repeat this funcion

function ChangeText(){
  var randNumber =  Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
  var quote = quotes[randNumber];
  var String = document.getElementById("LabelName");
  String.innerHTML = quote;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use setInterval, or better yet use setTimeout as below:

```
 var quotes = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
 function updateQuote(){
    var selectedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    container.innerText = quotes[selectedIndex];
    setTimeout(updateQuote,1000);
 }

 updateQuote();
```

working sample here: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview